# Update state of an object within the array - React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a state and within that state there is a list with several objects. What I basically want to do is take an index from this array, in this case `[0]`, and change its state. So, in short, I want to take `{id: "1", value: "world1"}`, and change the id to `'something'`. I made a code but it didn't come out as I expected.

```
this.state = {
   myState: [
              { id: "1", value:"world1" },
              { id: "2", value:"world2" },
              { id: "3", value:"world3" },
            ]
   }

const result = this.setState(prevState => ({
      myState: {
        ...prevState[0].id,
        id: 'something'
      }
    }))
```

console.log(result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need this, but the issue I'm seeing here is that myState is initially an array, and then you're passing it back as an object.

Try this:

```js
const result = this.setState(prevState => {
  prevState.myState[0].id = 'something';
  return prevState;
})
```

Comment: This will mutate the previous state

Answer (score 1):

```js
const state = {
  myState: [{
      id: "1",
      value: "world1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      value: "world2"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      value: "world3"
    },
  ]
}

const setState = (({
  myState
}) => {
  const newState = {
    myState: [...myState]
  }
  const array = newState.myState
  const targetIndex = array.findIndex(({
    id
  }) => id === '1')
  const item = array[targetIndex]
  array[targetIndex] = { ...item,
    id: 'something'
  }
  return newState;
})

console.log(setState(state))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.prototype.map and object spread operator

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        myState: prevState.myState.map(
            myStateItem => {
                if(myStateItem.id === '1') {
                    return {
                        ...myStateItem,
                        id: 'something'
                    }
                }
                return {
                    ...myStateItem
                }
        })
    };
});
```